# Parsing Xml with SAX Parser

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, sax

I am trying to parse an xml file with SAX Parser. 
I need to get attributes and it's values of a start element

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<API type="Connection">
<INFO server="com.com" function="getAccount2" />
<RESULT code="0">Operation Succeeded</RESULT>
<RESPONSE numaccounts="1">
<ACCOUNT login="fa051981" skynum="111111" maxaliases="1" creationdate="Fri Nov 16 00:59:59 2001"    password="pass" type="2222" status="open" mnemonic="32051981" ratelimit="0">
    <CHECKATTR />
    <REPLYATTR>Service-Type = Frames-User, Framed-Protocol = PPP, Framed-Routing = None</REPLYATTR>
    <SETTINGS bitval="4" status="open" />
    <SETTINGS bitval="8192" status="open" session_timeout="10800" />
    <SETTINGS bitval="32768" status="open" cisco_address_pool="thepool" />
    <ALIASES numaliases="0" />
</ACCOUNT>
</RESPONSE>
</API>
```

IN this xml, I need to get Settings tag/start element attributes along with it's values.

These attributes are dynamic, so I am trying to make a map of them. I am new to SAX Parser.

So far my java code:

```
public void startElement(String s, String s1, String elementName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

    if (elementName.equalsIgnoreCase(GenericConstants.INFO)) {
        this.searchRaidusBean.setServer(attributes.getValue(GenericConstants.SERVER));
        this.searchRaidusBean.setFunction(attributes.getValue(GenericConstants.FUNCTION));
    }
    if (elementName.equalsIgnoreCase(GenericConstants.RESULT)) {
        this.searchRaidusBean.setResultCode(attributes.getValue(GenericConstants.CODE));
    }

    if (elementName.equalsIgnoreCase(GenericConstants.ACCOUNT)) {
        this.searchRaidusBean.setLoginId(attributes.getValue(GenericConstants.LOGIN));
    }
    if (elementName.equalsIgnoreCase(GenericConstants.ACCOUNT)) {
        this.searchRaidusBean.setSkyNum(attributes.getValue(GenericConstants.SKYNUM));
    }
    if (elementName.equalsIgnoreCase(GenericConstants.ACCOUNT)) {
        this.searchRaidusBean.setMaxAliases(attributes.getValue(GenericConstants.MAXALIASES));
    }
    if (elementName.equalsIgnoreCase(GenericConstants.ACCOUNT)) {
        this.searchRaidusBean.setCreationDate(attributes.getValue(GenericConstants.CREATION_DATE));
    }
    if (elementName.equalsIgnoreCase(GenericConstants.ACCOUNT)) {
        this.searchRaidusBean.setType(attributes.getValue(GenericConstants.TYPE));
    }
    if (elementName.equalsIgnoreCase(GenericConstants.ACCOUNT)) {
        this.searchRaidusBean.setStatus(attributes.getValue(GenericConstants.STATUS));
    }
    if (elementName.equalsIgnoreCase(GenericConstants.ACCOUNT)) {
        this.searchRaidusBean.setMnemonic(attributes.getValue(GenericConstants.MNEMONIC));
    }
    if (elementName.equalsIgnoreCase(GenericConstants.ACCOUNT)) {
        this.searchRaidusBean.setRateLimit(attributes.getValue(GenericConstants.RATELIMIT));
    }
    if (elementName.equalsIgnoreCase(GenericConstants.SETTINGS)) {
        //this.searchRaidusBean.getBitval().add(attributes.getValue(GenericConstants.BITVAL));
        System.out.println(attributes);
        //stuck here
    }
    if (elementName.equalsIgnoreCase(GenericConstants.ALIASES)) {
        this.tempKey = attributes.getValue(GenericConstants.MNEMONIC);
    }
}



public void endElement(String str1, String str2, String element) throws SAXException {
    if (element.equalsIgnoreCase(GenericConstants.RESULT)) {
        this.searchRaidusBean.setResultMessage(this.tempValue);
    }
    if (element.equalsIgnoreCase(GenericConstants.ALIASES)) {
        if (!StringUtils.isBlank(this.tempKey)) {
            this.searchRaidusBean.getAlias().put(this.tempKey, this.tempValue);
        }
    }
}


public void characters(char[] charArray, int i, int j) throws SAXException {
    this.tempValue = new String(charArray, i, j);
}
```

Comment: There are whole lot of tutorial available on SAX parsing. SO is not the place where you get a program by just posting problem. You need to show your effort before posting for help.

Comment: Also, in the future, some example of code of what you've tried would be helpful, so we don't waste each others time barking up the wrong code path

Comment: Unless you are really required to use SAX (for example because of  homework assigment or outdated java version)  pull parser  will be better and easier alternative

Comment: is SAX parsing a requirement or you open to something better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the [DefaultHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/xml/sax/helpers/DefaultHandler.html), then you will be receiving a `startElement` event.

This method carries the [Attributes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/xml/sax/Attributes.html) as one of it's parameters.

You will need to use [getIndex(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/xml/sax/Attributes.html#getIndex(java.lang.String)) to get the index of the named attribute and [getValue(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/xml/sax/Attributes.html#getValue(int)) to get the value of said attribute.

As Nambari has pointed out, there are hundreds of tutorials on the internet and more then a few posts on the subject on SO (I answered one over the weekend).

**UPDATED**

I'd suggest it should look something like this (I've not tested it)

```
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String elementName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

    if (elementName.equalsIgnoreCase(GenericConstants.INFO)) {
        this.searchRaidusBean.setServer(attributes.getValue(GenericConstants.SERVER));
        this.searchRaidusBean.setFunction(attributes.getValue(GenericConstants.FUNCTION));
    }
    if (elementName.equalsIgnoreCase(GenericConstants.RESULT)) {
        this.searchRaidusBean.setResultCode(attributes.getValue(GenericConstants.CODE));
    }

    if (elementName.equalsIgnoreCase(GenericConstants.ACCOUNT)) {
        this.searchRaidusBean.setLoginId(attributes.getValue(GenericConstants.LOGIN));
        this.searchRaidusBean.setSkyNum(attributes.getValue(GenericConstants.SKYNUM));
        this.searchRaidusBean.setMaxAliases(attributes.getValue(GenericConstants.MAXALIASES));
        this.searchRaidusBean.setCreationDate(attributes.getValue(GenericConstants.CREATION_DATE));
        this.searchRaidusBean.setType(attributes.getValue(GenericConstants.TYPE));
        this.searchRaidusBean.setStatus(attributes.getValue(GenericConstants.STATUS));
        this.searchRaidusBean.setMnemonic(attributes.getValue(GenericConstants.MNEMONIC));
        this.searchRaidusBean.setRateLimit(attributes.getValue(GenericConstants.RATELIMIT));
    }

    if (elementName.equalsIgnoreCase(GenericConstants.SETTINGS)) {

        for (int index = 0; index < attributes.getLength(); index++) {

            String attName = attributes.getLocalName(index);
            String value = attributes.getValue(index);

            map.put(attName, value);

        }

    }

    if (elementName.equalsIgnoreCase(GenericConstants.ALIASES)) {
        this.tempKey = attributes.getValue(GenericConstants.MNEMONIC);
    }

}
```

**UPDATED with tested example**

I took you data (from the OP) and run it through the following handler

```
DefaultHandler handler = new DefaultHandler() {
    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("settings")) {

            System.out.println("Parse settings attributes...");

            for (int index = 0; index < attributes.getLength(); index++) {

                String aln = attributes.getLocalName(index);
                String value = attributes.getValue(index);

                System.out.println("    " + aln + " = " + value);


            }

        }

    }
};
```

And I got the following output

```
Parse settings attributes...
    bitval = 4
    status = open
Parse settings attributes...
    bitval = 8192
    status = open
    session_timeout = 10800
Parse settings attributes...
    bitval = 32768
    status = open
    cisco_address_pool = thepool
```

So I don't know what you're doing.

Comment: Added code to first post. I have gone through net tutorials and google search. put this particular case is not discussed.

Comment: But the above for loop fetches all attributes (including cascaded from parent node). thus it will contain ACCOUNT attributes like login, sknum also.

Comment: is it just me or SAX parsing code looks masochistic ?

Comment: @vtd-xml-author Sax uses a visitor pattern and isn't my preferred method of parsing xml

Comment: @vtd-xml-author No, moved on to Json